# bash syntax for regular expression

Tags: bash, syntax

I can't apply my tested regex with grouping in my bash script. what is the correct bash syntax to apply regex with grouping in variable?

I tested my regex with regex tester and worked. But I am still not able to this with bash. Now i understood more or less how the regex works but still i need to know how this apply in the script.

```
read_line="1- https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=wgG6xlQ1jx8  ==> movie name 1"
url=[[ "$read_line" =~ \d.*?(https.*?)==]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" #This syntax I copied from here. 

folder_name=[[ "$read_line" =~ ==>\s+(\w+.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

actual result should be:

```
url : https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=wgG6xlQ1jx8
folder_name: movie name 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ [[ "$read_line" =~ [0-9].*(https.*)== ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=wgG6xlQ1jx8  

$ [[ "$read_line" =~ '==>'[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]].*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
movie name 1
```

#### Comments

1. Bash does not support character classes such as `\d` or `\w`.  Bash uses POSIX regular expressions.
2. `[[ ... ]]` sets an error code but does not return a string.  Thus, variable assignments such as `var=[[ ... ]]` are not useful.
3. When using `[[` and `]]`, spaces matter.  Observe that this fails:

   ```
   $ [[ 1=1]] && echo yes
   bash: conditional binary operator expected
   bash: syntax error near `yes'
   ```

   But this succeeds:

   ```
   $ [[ 1 = 1 ]] && echo yes
   yes
   ```
4. Bash (POSIX) regular expressions always match the longest match.  They do not support non-greedy matches such as `.*?`.

#### Assigning values and catching missing matches

```
if [[ "$read_line" =~ '==>'[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]].*) ]]
then
    folder_name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
    echo "No Match"
fi
```

Comment: `[[ 1=1 ]]` works, but doesn't mean what it looks like; use `[[ 1 = 1 ]]` instead. Also, to assign the match to a variable, use e.g. `url="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`. It would also be good to handle the case where the string does *not* match. Oh, and the RE subexpression `.*?` doesn't make much sense, and isn't working for me. Use just `.*` instead.

Comment: @GordonDavisson  All excellent suggestions.   Thank you.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. No i know that posix regex.  Now the command is working like a charm. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the original bash codes,

> url=[[ "$read_line" =~ \d.*?(https.*?)==]] && echo
>   "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
>
> folder_name=[[ "$read_line" =~ ==>\s+(\w+.*) ]] && echo
>   "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

contains mistakes in terms of bash regex;
- `[[ ]]` regex is not meant as a RHS or right value whatsoever in expression so it'll error
- it has no shorthand feature; `\w, \d, \s`, etc supported by bash regex, must do [A-Za-z_], [0-9],[], etc but..
- fortunately it supports POSIX class set `\w by [[:alnum:]] \d by [[:digit:]] \s by [[:space:]]` so on, see its manual
- it has no 'lazy' quantifier feature `?` following repetition operator `*` or `+`
- inside regex place holder `[[ ]]`, some bash special character still applies such
 `\ > |` must be escaped as  `\\ \> \|` and also relational operator `== <=` etc

suggestion:
get/install better regex engine ie. better programming language with builtin better regex capabilities to get such done. Do it from inside `sed, perl, awk`, etc

to get goal, bash script may be;

```
[[ "$read_line" =~ (https:.*)' '== ]] && url=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
[[ "$read_line" =~ ==\>[[:space:]]+([ [:alnum:]]+) ]]&& folder_name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Comment: Abdan thank you too for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated.